# Pulovers Macro Creator IF command

Tags: pulovers-macro-creator

Using Pulover's Macro Creator v5.4.1 - I have a MSGBOX with a Yes/No selection that I want "NO" to just continue on to the next step, but if "YES" is selected it will goto a specific line in the macro, execute from that point until seeing the ENDIF, and then return to the next line (after the above MSGBOX) and continue. In basic it easy, but I have serched forums and anywhere else that Google takes me but I can seem to get this one down, Thanks in advance!!

I have serched forums and anywhere else that Google takes me but I can seem to get this one down, I thought that it would be in the MSGBOX command. I am just looking at a simple way to automate repetitive desktop functions or processes and PMC has done 99% of what I want for free. If anyone knows of something else that is free, PLEASE let me know, thanks!